# How to declaratively implement custom IAuthorizationPolicy in WCF?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service that is hosted in IIS.  I want to use my own IAuthorizationPolicy, and have it configured in the web.config file on the server.  I have my auth policy:

```
namespace MyLib.WCF
{
    public class CustomAuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
    {
        public CustomAuthorizationPolicy()
        {
            this.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Testing custom auth");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

And in my web.config:

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="Behavior" name="MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding"  contract="IMyService"/>               
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Behavior">
        <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Custom">
            <authorizationPolicies>
        <add policyType="MyLib.WCF.CustomAuthorizationPolicy, MyLib.WCF, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
            </authorizationPolicies>
        </serviceAuthorization>
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

But my CustomAuthorizationPolicy.Evaluate() method never fires.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious (silly) question is: in your `<service>`, do you actually reference your behavior configuration??

I.e. do you have:

```
<system.serviceModel>    
 ....
   <service name="YourService" behaviorConfiguration="Behavior">
       ....
   </service>
 ....
</system.serviceModel>
```

Just defining all your stuff is nice and well - but unless you've actually referenced it, it won't do you any good (been there, done that myself, too! :-) )

Second (almost as silly) question would be: what binding and security config do you use?? Have you even turned on security at all?  If you have `<security mode="None">`, then your service authorization will obviously never be used, either (since no credentials are being passed to the service at all).

Marc

Comment: Great questions, it's usually the obvious things that get me!  I've added my service config to the code snippet above, but to answer your questions:  1) Yes I'm referencing my behaviorConfiguration, 2)  I'm using wsHttpBinding but I don't have a Security mode set - maybe that defaults to None?

Comment: No, actually, the wsHttp binding defaults to message based security using Windows credentials. That shouldn't be the problem....