# WCF override Role based security check

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, security

I've have an ASP.NET application running in VS2010.
To access the wcf services from the client one needs to have the proper roles. I Need to test the application on a 
machine where those roles are not available.

Is it possible to disable PrincipalPermission check for all services in web.config or in any other way without modifying the sourcecode ? Or is there a way to provide the 'AppRole' - role somewhere as a config parameter ?

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "AppRole")]
public string GetFoo()
{
    // return ..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable the check, but all you need to do is to set `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to an `IPrincipal` that has the required roles.

One way to do this is to configure a `RoleProvider` in the application configuration file on your test machine with the appropriate roles.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know what you mean by 'configure a RoleProvider', do you have any example of that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a generic principal with roles that you want at the run time. The roles can come from the config file.

Using IAuthorizationPolicy you can install generic principal. See this [SO: How to declaratively implement custom IAuthorizationPolicy in WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322682/how-to-declaratively-implement-custom-iauthorizationpolicy-in-wcf)

Some more info:

[msdn: IAuthorizationPolicy Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.policy.iauthorizationpolicy.aspx)

[Custom Principals and WCF](http://leastprivilege.com/2007/08/08/custom-principals-and-wcf/)